# How to list all the USB devices (printers) connected on yocto?

Tags: yocto, cups, lsusb

I am trying to get a USB printer to work with an embedded system using yocto. I have the cups package added to the yocto image. The lpstat command returns that no default destination is available. I am trying to see if my printer gets listed via lsusb, but lsusb does not seem to be a recognized command. busybox lsusb doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busybox doesn't provide `lsusb` but usbutils does.
As you can see [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-bsp/usbutils/usbutils_008.bb):

`Contains the lsusb utility for inspecting the devices connected to the USB bus.`

Also, I invite you to use `dmesg` to understand what happens with the device.